# How to bind a DataGridView to a list of custom classes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, vb.net-2010

I have a list of custom classes that I am building using a `TableAdapter`.

I want to add these to a `DataGridView` binding certain columns only.

I have tried the code below to fill and bind the data:

```
lAllBookings = (From r As DataRow In BookingsTableAdapter1.GetDataWithItems().Rows
                        Select New Booking With {.bookingID = r.Item("BookingID"), _
                                                 .itemID = r.Item("ItemID"), _
                                                 .bookedOutDate = r.Field(Of DateTime?)("BookedOutDate"), _
                                                 .bookedInDate = r.Field(Of DateTime?)("BookedInDate"), _
                                                 .identType = r.Item("IdentType"), _
                                                 .identString = r.Item("IdentString"), _
                                                 .image = r.Item("Image"), _
                                                 .complete = r.Item("Complete"), _
                                                 .notes = r.Item("Notes"), _
                                                 .itemName = r.Item("ItemName"), _
                                                 .itemBC = r.Item("ItemBarcode")}).ToList



        dgvBookings.Columns("BookingID").DataPropertyName = "bookingID"
        dgvBookings.Columns("ItemIdent").DataPropertyName = "itemName"
        dgvBookings.Columns("BookedOut").DataPropertyName = "bookedOutDate"
        dgvBookings.Columns("IdentString").DataPropertyName = "identString"


        dgvBookings.DataSource = lAllBookings
```

Now when I do this I get the correct number of rows but all fields are blank.

I've run through a few questions on SO and a few tutorials but they all seem to do things slightly different to what I need.

Is there a way I can fill the `DataGridView` using my list of items?
I'd rather avoid using a `DataSet` if I can as I've built a lot of other code on this `List<Of  Class>` type.

Edit - Here is the Class `Booking` declaration:

```
Public Class Booking

    Public bookingID As Integer
    Public itemID As Integer
    Public itemName As String
    Public itemBC As String

    Public identType As Short
    Public identString As String
    Public image As Byte()
    Public complete As Boolean
    Public notes As String

    Public bookedInDate As DateTime?
    Public bookedOutDate As DateTime?

End Class
```

Answer (score 8):

I know is really late for you but maybe it can help someone.

I had the same problem that you but using vb.net.

Finally I found the solution: Your class was not exposing properties but variables. The binding system looks for properties and can't find them so you get the empty rows.

Try to complete your class adding `{get; set;}` (or the Property attribute if using vb.net) and everything will work.

Hope it can be helpful.

Comment: You saved me a lot of headache! Thank you, kind sir!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that you are getting in `IAllBookings` all the information you want. In any case, you are not passing it rightly to the `dgvBookings`. Here you have a couple of small codes to help you to understand how this works better:

```
dgvBookings.Columns.Clear()    
Dim newTable As New DataTable

newTable.Columns.Add("Column1")
newTable.Columns.Add("Column2")
newTable.Columns.Add("Column3")

newTable.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3")
newTable.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3")
newTable.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3")

dgvBookings.DataSource = newTable
```

The `newTable` emulates perfectly the `DataGridView` structure (columns & rows) and thus it can be given as a `DataSource` directly.

Unlikely the case of a simple List:

```
dgvBookings.Columns.Clear()
Dim newList = New List(Of String)
newList.Add("1")
newList.Add("2")
newList.Add("3")

dgvBookings.DataSource = newList
```

You are providing less information than expected (1D vs. the expected 2D) and thus the result is not the one you want. You need to provide more information; for example: instead of relying on DataSource, you might add the rows one by one:

```
dgvBookings.Columns.Add("Column1", "Column1")
For Each item In newList
    dgvBookings.Rows.Add(item)
Next
```

I hope that this answer will help you to understand better how to deal with `DataGridView` and with the different data sources.

-- UPDATE

Row by row option applied to your specific case.

```
For Each item As Booking In lAllBookings
    With item
        dgvBookings.Rows.Add(.bookingID.ToString(), .itemID.ToString(), .bookedOutDate.ToString(), .identString.ToString())
    End With
Next
```

Comment: The first dimension is the list, the second is the different public variables of the data class I am using. I will add the class declaration.

Comment: So, the list is not a list of strings, but a list of this class which has, implicitely, 2D information. I understand what you intend and cannot say categorically that is not possible. What I can confirm is that doing this kind of things is not straightforward (same thing with a dictionary). The "DataSource" has a simplistic understanding, what you are putting there is too complex. If you do a small loop right after assigning the value to lAllBookings, converting its value into a DataTable, as shown in my example, it would work without any problems.

Comment: Or you might change the query such that the datatable is populated directly. Both options will output a for sure-working approach. Inputting your class directly (which, on the other hand, have different types) and make this work will not be easy.

Comment: @bendataclear I have updated my answer to show the adaptation of the row-by-row proposal to your specific case. It is really quick to implement and, unless having a really big input dataset, it will not have a serious impact in performance. It seems like the easiest/most practical solution for you. Bear in mind that you cannot do that (add rows) when the DataSource is different than Nothing.

Comment: This would be much simpler if I were using `LINQ` as this allows binding to a list of classes, is there any way to copy that functionality?

Comment: @bendataclear hi again (it has been a while since our last chat :)), what I propose is not so difficult (actually adapting your code as suggested would take just one minute) and intending to do what you want might become tricky. You have to bear in mind that you are populating a 2D dataset and thus you would have to create a 2D-query (something much more difficult than what I proposed). You would have to create a DataTable (a 2D Collection), for example (and populate this DataTable via Linq) and then feed this DataTable to the DataGridView as DataSource...

Comment: @bendataclear I don't like Linq-like statements too much because they are not as evident and "easily buildable" as a simple loop  (and actually are not even quicker than the loop). They look nice and seem to make things simpler but this is just the appearance: creating a properly-working query for a more or less complex situation is not straightforward; you have to spend more time on it than on building a loop (even though the code length might be much smaller). Also in case of having to extend/adapt it in the future, you might find problems.

Comment: @bendataclear if you have an already-done Linq query which you can easily adapt here or a guy enjoying creating Linq queries (quite a few of them in this site :)), not minding to do one for you; just use it. Otherwise, I would recommend you to not waste too much time on something which, at the end, would just look nice in the code but wouldn't have a relevant (positive) impact on the performance, neither on the scalability/adaptability of your approach. In any case, have completely clear that I will not create such a query; I think that I have done more than enough to answer your question :)

Comment: The LINQ isn't the interesting bit for me, it's the binding, I want to change/filter the list as the user types in one place rather than changing/filtering the main list of classes and clearing then re-looping to fill the datagridview

Comment: @bendataclear the binding is very easy: the dataGridView expects a 2D DataSource, provide a 2D DataSource, for example: a DataTable, as suggested in my answer (you are inputting a 1D Collection and this is the problem). You can use anything you want (LINQ or not) to populate this DataTable. Alternatively, you might introduce the Rows/Columns one by one without relying on DataSource, also as suggested on my answer. Please, understand what I replied and use it: these are the only two options you have; but you can implement any of these options by relying on different methodologies.