# Add items to datagrid programmatically

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have added a datagrid in WPF/VB.NET, managed to create columns in code but i can't figure out how to add rows to datagrid.

```
 Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
    Dim c1 As New DataGridTextColumn()
    c1.Header = "Šifra"
    c1.Width = 100
    c1.Binding = New Binding("Šifra")
    gridRacun.Columns.Add(c1)

    Dim c2 As New DataGridTextColumn()
    c2.Header = "Naziv artikla"
    c2.Width = 500
    c2.Binding = New Binding("Naziv artikla")
    gridRacun.Columns.Add(c2)

    Dim c3 As New DataGridTextColumn()
    c3.Header = "Količina"
    c3.Width = 100
    c3.Binding = New Binding("Količina")
    gridRacun.Columns.Add(c3)

    Dim c4 As New DataGridTextColumn()
    c4.Header = "Cijena"
    c4.Width = 100
    c4.Binding = New Binding("Cijena")
    gridRacun.Columns.Add(c4)


End Sub
```

How would i add strings to datagrid for each column, strings are contents of 4 labels which will change and on button click i wish to set label1.content to column1, lebel2.content to column2 etc.?

Comment: What about `gridRacun.Items.Add(myItem);`?

Comment: How would i create myItem? @michip96

Comment: myItem has to be an object of a class which contains public properties for all your bindings. In example you can add a binding to `c1` like so: `c1.Binding = New Binding("Name")`. Then the object myItem should have a public property `Name` which value will be displayed in the column `c1` if you add the item to the `gridRacun`.

Comment: I can also give you an example if you want. @RaceLt

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to create object that i can add to grid. It's not working. :) If you can, please do, thank you @michip96

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom items to your DataGrid by creating a class which holds the item's values in it:

```
Class Item
    Private _name As String

    Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    //Some other properties
End Class
```

Now you can create your DataGrid column like this:

```
Dim myColumn As New DataGridTextColumn()

myColumn.Header = "Name"
myColumn.Binding = New Binding("Name")

dataGrid.Columns.Add(myColumn)
```

You can now add rows by adding items to your DataGrid:

```
Dim item = New Item With {.Name = "Terry Adams"}
dataGrid.Items.Add(item)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This way it only adds empty rows. Might be i'm doing something wrong, will check more.

Comment: This is what i get when i console.write(item): `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Sifra' property not found on 'object' ''Item' (HashCode=22466860)'. BindingExpression:Path=Sifra; DataItem='Item' (HashCode=22466860); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
`

Comment: I edited my answer due to this post on so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34921647/2601107

In VB.net the binding system is looking for properties and not attributes. So you need to set a property as i showed above. Concerning your error message do you have a property called Sifra in your Item class?

Comment: It works perfect... thank you so much. i'll start researching further. you're a gem